# Find a meromorphic function with given principal parts

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have the homework problem of finding an "elementary" meromorphic function $f(z)$ with the same principal parts as the sum $$\frac{1}{\pi z^2} + \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\cos n}{z^2 - n^2}$$ (and, for extra credit, computing the sum itself).  I don't know how to proceed; I've been blindly trying several likely-seeming trigonometric functions, but with no success.  I've tried to manipulate various cotangent identities, such as $$\pi \cot (\pi z) = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2z}{z^2 - n^2},$$ into the desired form, but didn't really get anywhere with it, because I'm not sure how to handle the alternating sum.

EDIT: Response to Robert Israel's comment.  My first thought is to rewrite the given sum as $$\frac{1}{\pi z^2} + \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\cos n}{z^2 - n^2} = \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n \cos n}{z} \frac{1}{z-n}.$$  Then, if we try to evaluate, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $$\lim_{z \to n} \sin (\pi z) \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^k \cos k}{\pi z(z-k)},$$
then all the terms in the sum except for $k=n$, being finite, vanish at the limit when multiplied by $\sin (\pi z)$, leaving $$\lim_{z \to n} \frac{(-1)^n \cos n \sin (\pi z)}{\pi z(z-n)} = \lim_{z \to n} \frac{(-1)^n \cos n \cos (\pi z)}{2z - n} = \frac{ (-1)^n \cos n \cos (\pi n)}{n} = \frac{\cos n}{n},$$ implying that the sum's principal parts should agree with those of $z \mapsto \cos z/z \sin z$; is this reasoning correct?  Graphing $\sin (\pi z)$ times the fifteenth partial sum of the original sum (with domain restricted to the reals) shows a function that looks plausibly close to $z \mapsto \cos z/z$.  Also, is there a similar way one could prove the equality of the sum and $\cos z/z \sin (\pi z)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If it was $f(z) = g(z)/\sin(\pi z)$, what would $g(n)$ be?

Comment: I think I understand what you're hinting at.  See my edit to the original question.